# UnityLink with Wolfram Engine, possible?

Tags: free-wolfram-engine

I only have a license for 11.0.1 for OS X. I recently installed free Wolfram Engine and can use it with jupyter notebook. I wonder if it is possible to use UnityLink with WE, or is it only available with Mathematica 12?  Best,

Comment: Ought to be. Give it a try and let us know how it works or where you get stuck.

Comment: How did you manage to activate your license for Wolfram Engine? I keep getting the error message `Cannot connect to https://www.wolframcloud.com` even though I have a developer license. I have even written to Wolfram Research, but to no avail.

Comment: Yes, UnityLink is part of the Wolfram Engine.

Comment: UnityLink is actually a paclet that needs to be downloaded. It should be downloaded the first time do you ``<<UnityLink` ``. It is large, so this might take quite a while.